# Cassandra nodetool decommission

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, nodetool

I wish to decommission a cassandra node as that node needs a OS upgrade.

I login to that node. Execute the decommission command and after few minutes i get this exception on console

```
nodetool decommission

error: Stream failed
-- StackTrace --
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:208)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:184)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:412)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:507)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:229)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure what that exception means, I intend to verify if decommission is successful through **nodetool netstats** and **nodetool status** whoose output is below. In both the places it says **LEAVING**, how do i confirm if it's complete.

```
nodetool netstats
Mode: LEAVING
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 1
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Commands                        n/a         0             26
Responses                       n/a         0         758780

nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UL  x.x.x.x  1.02 MB    256     ?       377869a9-d01c-4b7d-a24c-dbb90afee3d8  RAC1
```

My cassandra version is 2.1.8. Found a reference bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10371 which says it might take 72 hours for the changes to reflect.

Should I [assassinate the node](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204225949-Removing-Unreachable-Nodes-from-Gossip) as mentioned in the [Removing a node doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRemoveNode.html#opsRemoveNode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't see the node in `nodetool status`, then its confirmed that its completed. If not, then you can try `nodetool removenode` to remove the node from the cluster. `nodetool assassinate` is the last option for you to remove the node from the cluster. If `nodetool removenode` failed to remove the node from the cluster, then we use `nodetool assassinate` to remove node.

Error Issue: To see more details of this ERROR, `cat /install_directory/apache-cassandra-2.1.8/logs/system.log | grep ERROR`

Your node failed to stream data with other nodes. This type of issues arises for many reason, for example: users process limit (nproc). Find more details about your issue to find out the reason of your ERROR.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped debug after looking into system.log. One of the cluster node was down to which stream failed.